# cannot see my controllers in codeigniter 4 with MAMP on MacOS Catalina

Tags: php, codeigniter, mamp

I'm trying to install Codeigniter 4 on My dev machine running macOS Catalina
Right now I have developed applications using CI v3 but I would like to migrate to v4 so I'm testing stuff

I'm following the guide
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/

my MAMP install (MAMP 5.7) have php 7.4.2 installed and phpinfo(); shows intl extension enabled

```
PHP Version 7.4.2

ICU version 56.1
```

Installing CI4 with composer gives me errors

`composer create-project codeigniter4/appstarter test_ci4_2`

output:

```
     Installing codeigniter4/appstarter (v4.0.4)
       - Installing codeigniter4/appstarter (v4.0.4): Loading from cache
     Created project in /Users/filippoferrari/Documenti/MAMP/htdocs/test_ci4_2
     Loading composer repositories with package information
     Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
     Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
     
       Problem 1
         - codeigniter4/framework v4.0.4 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
         - codeigniter4/framework v4.0.3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
         - codeigniter4/framework v4.0.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
        - codeigniter4/framework v4.0.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
         - codeigniter4/framework 4.0.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
         - Installation request for codeigniter4/framework ^4 -> satisfiable by codeigniter4/framework[4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4].
```

so I switched to the "manual" install.
I have created a folder named TEST_CI4 under MAMP/htdocs folder and put CI4 files there
Under App/Config/app.php I set up public $baseURL = 'http://localhost:8888/test_ci4_2/'; (my apache runs on port 8888)

if I point my browser to http://localhost:8888/test_ci4/public/ I see the codeigniter Welcome page

but if I point my browser to http://localhost:8888/test_ci4/ I see the folder structure.

the problem is that, following the tutorial and creating the "Pages" controller when I open the browser with http://localhost:8888/test_ci4/pages/ I have the "404 not found" error.

Did I miss some steps that the composer installation would do automagically?

Answer (score 0):

"Develop your app inside the app folder, and the public folder will be your document root" - CI user guide

Basicly on localhost you will always need to append public dir because thats your document root and files like index.php, css,javascript etc. will go into that folder.

On web servers they encouraging you to add app,system folders above document root and public or on webservers public_html will be your root folder. Also on webservers with domain you wont need to add public.